# SQL Azure and Indexes

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

is that true that SQL Azure rebuilds / reorganizes index automatically?

We have a database on Sql Azure and experiencing performance degradation and I suppose this is a urban-legend.

Can you help me?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQL Azure does not rebuild indexes automatically while the statistics are updated automatically.
If you have a specific reason to force the rebuild it, you have to directly issue the command.

This nice post helps you create a script to [dynamically rebuild all indexes in a SQL Azure db](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dilkushp/archive/2013/07/28/fragmentation-in-sql-azure.aspx).

Comment: I've experimented right now and I saw that my tables' indexes are dramatically fragmented. I really hope that with a rebuild all, everything gets back to normality.

Comment: The link you posted is broken, can you update it please?

Answer (score 0):

Sql Azure offers few nice amenities with it, as follows:

Intelligent Performance
  Performance overview
  Performance recommendations
  Query Performance Insight
  Automatic tuning

Keep an eye on the statistics, You can also allow azure to automatically tune your database indexes, add, remove them to tune database performance.

Hope it helps.