# Azure SQL query slow

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have setup an Azure SQL database.  My goal to to evaluate it for use on a real project.

I have a simple query that is very slow.

```
select *
from table1 T1 join table2 T2
        on T1 .T2_id = T2.id
```

On my laptop SQL Server this is sub-second but in azure it's 11 seconds.

`Table1` has 6,643 rows and table2 has 12 rows.

The execution plan is identical on both SQL Servers.

If I just return a `count(*)` it's sub-second in both places.

The execution plan contains a clustered index scan of `Table1`'s primary key which is 90% of the cost (in both environments).  With the `count(*)`, this scan is not in the plan.

I am using the basic 'service tier' but there is very little data I am the only user.  This is a test, but I can't put anything into production with this performance.

Edit: I upgraded to Standard tier, with "S2 50 DTUS's" - the highest in standard tier.  I am still having the problem.

Comment: You can read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086778/why-is-running-a-query-on-sql-azure-so-much-slower)

Comment: This must be a *very* weak instance. That query is *nothing* even without indices. That's like a dozen pages read and a few ms of CPU.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure IO is throttled using Database Throughput Units (DTUs). I suspect you are hitting your limit, although on the surface this certainly doesn't sound like an expensive query.

Here's a similiar question that goes into some in-depth analysis of a similiar problem: [Simple select count(id) uses 100% of Azure SQL DTUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073079/simple-select-countid-uses-100-of-azure-sql-dtus)

Ultimately, the quick way to find out is this: try a higher-end plan for a few minutes and see what happens.

Comment: I upgraded to Standard tier, with "S2 50 DTUS's" - the highest in standard tier.  I am still having the problem.  I updated the original question.

Comment: On the monitor screen I see that the DTU percentage is 1.2%.  I assume this means I have not reached the DTU limit.
Why would this be so slow?